# Hyperledger Explorer Database Setup

Tags: sql, postgresql, ubuntu-16.04, hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

I am trying to set up Hyperledger explorer using the official docs
https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer
In the DB creation process when I run ./createdb.sh. ** I get the error Unable to Initialize policy plugin. **

Comment: were you able to fix it ?

Comment: Yes i was. I installed postgres manually on the server. 
Then followed the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Dont run with normal privilege , Try to run with sudo permissions.

```
chmod +x createdb.sh 
sudo -u postgres ./createdb.sh
```